# Able to re-access a POST request after navigating away from the page. Why?

Tags: java, html, httprequest, httpresponse

I submit a form on the browser using the "submit" button. I set the parameters to be sent by the POST method. The my local server sends the response html page via a servlet using the parameters in the request. From my understanding, POST requests cannot be bookmarked. However after I navigate to another page from the response, I can still access the page when I press the back button on the browser.

Is this because the browser saves the page? Or is my understanding of POST request incorrect?

Thank You!

Comment: `I can still access the page when I press the back button on the browser` is because of the browser cache it has nothing to do with `POST`.When you press browser back button you are not sending request to server its just the view with data that is saved in browser cache

Comment: It's hard to reason about what some code does and why it behaves in a certain way without knowing precisely what the code does. Post the code.